# Triggering zero-byte reads on FIFO/pty

Tags: fifo, read, pty

I'd like to know how to emulate the ICANON behavior of ^D: namely, trigger an immediate, even zero-byte, read in the program on the other end of a FIFO or PTY or socket or somesuch.  In particular, I have a program whose specification is that it reads a script on stdin up until it gets a zero byte read, then reads input to feed the script, and I'd like to automatically test this functionality.

Simply writing to a FIFO doesn't result in the right thing happening, of course, since there's no zero byte read.  Help?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a pretty significant difference between the various reader/writer behaviors of the different types of files you mention. Is it a pty or fifo or socket that you really need to work with? Anyway, if you want to trigger end of file on a pipe, you have to close the pipe. You can save it on another fd temporarily, then reopen it. If the reader tries to read in the meantime it will see EOF - you'd wanna trap its reaction, probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this behavior is unique to terminal devices, so that's what you have to use.

Use a pseudo-tty whose slave side is in `ICANON` mode, and write <kbd>Ctl-d</kbd> (`'\4'`) to the master side.

Comment: And one program to aid one in doing so is `ptybandage`, available in Dan Bernstein's 1999 "ptyget" package (based upon his original "pty" package published to `comp.sources.unix`, volume 25 issues 127 to 135, in 1992), in Paul Jarc's [updated version](http://code.dogmap.org./ptyget/), and in [the nosh source package](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh.html) as an [execline](http://skarnet.org./software/execline/) script that uses nosh terminal management tools.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
echo -n '' > /path/to/the/fifo
```

`echo -n` produces no newlines and `''` is an empty string. So that should result in nothing (0 bytes) being written into the fifo.

You can shorten that `echo` down to literally nothing:

```
> /path/to/the/fifo
```

(if you're careful not to misunderstand it as piping some other output)

Comment: It's a guess - the question needs more context.